# rosmake fails on OS X

Tags: rosmake, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running `rosmake -a` as per http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source fails on OS X 10.8.2. Previous steps succeeded find.

<del>Most of the errors seemed to be concerned with this Python module `urandom`...</del> These have been fixed now. The remaining errors concern x86_64/i386 symbols not being found?

Here's the full log:

http://pastie.org/pastes/6368348/text

Any ideas, folks?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56553/rosmake-fails-on-os-x/) by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-03-12**:
Guys, does anyone know how to solve this?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-12**:
@Noldorin There are three separate errors in that log. I'll try to answer them each, but in the future you should try to narrow the question down.

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-03-12**:
@William: Okay, fair enough; I did just think they were somewhat related, but maybe not... Thanks, look forward to your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first error is with `nodelet_tutorial_math`:

```
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: /Users/alex/ros_ws/common_tutorials/nodelet_tutorial_math/build
  cd build && make -j -l8
  Scanning dependencies of target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  Scanning dependencies of target rosbuild_precompile
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  Scanning dependencies of target nodelet_math
  [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/nodelet_math.dir/src/plus.cpp.o
  Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libnodelet_math.dylib
  clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "class_loader::class_loader_private::AbstractMetaObjectBase::addOwningClassLoader(class_loader::ClassLoader*)", referenced from:
        void class_loader::class_loader_private::registerPlugin<nodelet_tutorial_math::Plus, nodelet::Nodelet>(std::string const&, std::string const&) in plus.cpp.o
    "class_loader::class_loader_private::AbstractMetaObjectBase::setAssociatedLibraryPath(std::string)", referenced from:
        void class_loader::class_loader_private::registerPlugin<nodelet_tutorial_math::Plus, nodelet::Nodelet>(std::string const&, std::string const&) in plus.cpp.o
    "class_loader::class_loader_private::AbstractMetaObjectBase::AbstractMetaObjectBase(std::string const&, std::string const&)", referenced from:
        class_loader::class_loader_private::AbstractMetaObject<nodelet::Nodelet>::AbstractMetaObject(std::string const&, std::string const&) in plus.cpp.o
    "class_loader::class_loader_private::AbstractMetaObjectBase::~AbstractMetaObjectBase()", referenced from:
        class_loader::class_loader_private::AbstractMetaObject<nodelet::Nodelet>::AbstractMetaObject(std::string const&, std::string const&) in plus.cpp.o
    "class_loader::class_loader_private::getFactoryMapForBaseClass(std::string const&)", referenced from:
        std::map<std::string, class_loader::class_loader_private::AbstractMetaObjectBase*, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, class_loader::class_loader_private::AbstractMetaObjectBase*> > >& class_loader::class_loader_private::getFactoryMapForBaseClass<nodelet::Nodelet>() in plus.cpp.o
    "class_loader::class_loader_private::getCurrentlyActiveClassLoader()", referenced from:
        void class_loader::class_loader_private::registerPlugin<nodelet_tutorial_math::Plus, nodelet::Nodelet>(std::string const&, std::string const&) in plus.cpp.o
    "class_loader::class_loader_private::getCurrentlyLoadingLibraryName()", referenced from:
        void class_loader::class_loader_private::registerPlugin<nodelet_tutorial_math::Plus, nodelet::Nodelet>(std::string const&, std::string const&) in plus.cpp.o
    "class_loader::class_loader_private::getPluginBaseToFactoryMapMapMutex()", referenced from:
        void class_loader::class_loader_private::registerPlugin<nodelet_tutorial_math::Plus, nodelet::Nodelet>(std::string const&, std::string const&) in plus.cpp.o
    "class_loader::class_loader_private::hasANonPurePluginLibraryBeenOpened(bool)", referenced from:
        void class_loader::class_loader_private::registerPlugin<nodelet_tutorial_math::Plus, nodelet::Nodelet>(std::string const&, std::string const&) in plus.cpp.o
    "console_bridge::log(char const*, int, console_bridge::LogLevel, char const*, ...)", referenced from:
        void class_loader::class_loader_private::registerPlugin<nodelet_tutorial_math::Plus, nodelet::Nodelet>(std::string const&, std::string const&) in plus.cpp.o
        __GLOBAL__I_a in plus.cpp.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  make[3]: *** [../lib/libnodelet_math.dylib] Error 1
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/nodelet_math.dir/all] Error 2
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package nodelet_tutorial_math written to:
[ rosmake ]    /Users/alex/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130302-173409/nodelet_tutorial_math/build_output.log
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< nodelet_tutorial_math [FAIL] [ 41.04 seconds ]
```

It appears that it is not linking against `class_loader` correctly.

I created a ticket:

https://github.com/ros/common_tutorials/issues/3

---

Next is `orocos_kdl`, which appears to be missing a link against CppUnit:

```
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        FramesTest::suite() in framestest.cpp.o
    "CppUnit::TextTestRunner::result() const", referenced from:
        _main in test-runner.cpp.o
    "CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase::getTestNameFor(std::string const&) const", referenced from:
        FramesTest::addTestsToSuite(CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase&) in framestest.cpp.o
    "CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase::makeTestFixture() const", referenced from:
        FramesTest::addTestsToSuite(CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase&) in framestest.cpp.o
    "CppUnit::Test::findTestPath(CppUnit::Test const*, CppUnit::TestPath&) const", referenced from:
        vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<FramesTest> in framestest.cpp.o
    "CppUnit::Test::findTestPath(std::string const&, CppUnit::TestPath&) const", referenced from:
        vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<FramesTest> in framestest.cpp.o
    "CppUnit::Test::getChildTestAt(int) const", referenced from:
        vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<FramesTest> in framestest.cpp.o
    "CppUnit::Test::resolveTestPath(std::string const&) const", referenced from:
        vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<FramesTest> in framestest.cpp.o
    "CppUnit::Test::checkIsValidIndex(int) const", referenced from:
        vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<FramesTest> in framestest.cpp.o
    "CppUnit::Test::findTest(std::string const&) const", referenced from:
        vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<FramesTest> in framestest.cpp.o
    "CppUnit::TestCase::getName() const", referenced from:
        vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<FramesTest> in framestest.cpp.o
    "CppUnit::TestLeaf::countTestCases() const", referenced from:
        vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<FramesTest> in framestest.cpp.o
    "CppUnit::TestLeaf::doGetChildTestAt(int) const", referenced from:
        vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<FramesTest> in framestest.cpp.o
    "CppUnit::TestLeaf::getChildTestCount() const", referenced from:
        vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<FramesTest> in framestest.cpp.o
    "typeinfo for CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase", referenced from:
        typeinfo for CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContext<FramesTest> in framestest.cpp.o
    "typeinfo for CppUnit::TestCase", referenced from:
        typeinfo for CppUnit::TestCaller<FramesTest> in framestest.cpp.o
    "vtable for CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase", referenced from:
        CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContext<FramesTest>::TestSuiteBuilderContext(CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase&) in framestest.cpp.o
    NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  make[3]: *** [tests/framestest] Error 1
  make[2]: *** [tests/CMakeFiles/framestest.dir/all] Error 2
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package orocos_kdl written to:
[ rosmake ]    /Users/alex/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130302-173409/orocos_kdl/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< orocos_kdl [FAIL] [ 43.92 seconds ]
```

In this case I would suggest you ensure you have cppunit installed and try building `orocos_kdl` by itself (`rosmake orocos_kdl`).

---

Finally there is `rviz_plugin_tutorials`, which seems to have some c++ which clang is not happy with:

```
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
  -- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - found
  -- Looking for QT_MAC_USE_COCOA
  -- Looking for QT_MAC_USE_COCOA - found
  -- Found Qt4: /usr/local/bin/qmake (found version "4.8.4") 
  [rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /Users/alex/ros_ws/visualization_tutorials/rviz_plugin_tutorials/build/src/moc_drive_widget.cxx; assuming that it is in /Users/alex/ros_ws/visualization_tutorials/rviz_plugin_tutorials and will be generated later
  [rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /Users/alex/ros_ws/visualization_tutorials/rviz_plugin_tutorials/build/src/moc_imu_display.cxx; assuming that it is in /Users/alex/ros_ws/visualization_tutorials/rviz_plugin_tutorials and will be generated later
  [rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /Users/alex/ros_ws/visualization_tutorials/rviz_plugin_tutorials/build/src/moc_plant_flag_tool.cxx; assuming that it is in /Users/alex/ros_ws/visualization_tutorials/rviz_plugin_tutorials and will be generated later
  [rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /Users/alex/ros_ws/visualization_tutorials/rviz_plugin_tutorials/build/src/moc_teleop_panel.cxx; assuming that it is in /Users/alex/ros_ws/visualization_tutorials/rviz_plugin_tutorials and will be generated later
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: /Users/alex/ros_ws/visualization_tutorials/rviz_plugin_tutorials/build
  cd build && make -j -l8
  Scanning dependencies of target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  Scanning dependencies of target rosbuild_precompile
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  [  7%] Generating src/moc_teleop_panel.cxx
  [ 15%] Generating src/moc_plant_flag_tool.cxx
  [ 23%] Generating src/moc_imu_display.cxx
  [ 30%] Generating src/moc_drive_widget.cxx
  Scanning dependencies of target rviz_plugin_tutorials
  [ 38%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rviz_plugin_tutorials.dir/src/drive_widget.cpp.o
  /Users/alex/ros_ws/visualization_tutorials/rviz_plugin_tutorials/src/drive_widget.cpp:113:23: error: variable length array of non-POD element type 'QPointF'
      QPointF left_track[ step_count ];
                        ^
  /Users/alex/ros_ws/visualization_tutorials/rviz_plugin_tutorials/src/drive_widget.cpp:114:24: error: variable length array of non-POD element type 'QPointF'
      QPointF right_track[ step_count ];
                         ^
  In file included from /Users/alex/ros_ws/visualization_tutorials/rviz_plugin_tutorials/src/drive_widget.cpp:34:
  In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.4/include/QtGui/QMouseEvent:1:
  In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.4/include/QtGui/qevent.h:52:
  /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.4/include/QtGui/qmime.h:119:10: warning: private field 'type' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
      char type;
           ^
  1 warning and 2 errors generated.
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/rviz_plugin_tutorials.dir/src/drive_widget.cpp.o] Error 1
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rviz_plugin_tutorials.dir/all] Error 2
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package rviz_plugin_tutorials written to:
[ rosmake ]    /Users/alex/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130302-173409/rviz_plugin_tutorials/build_output.log
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rviz_plugin_tutorials [FAIL] [ 25.69 seconds ]
```

I filed a ticket:

https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials/issues/3

---

Finally, I would say that you don't need any of these packages, the two tutorial packages obviously need to be fixed but are not crucial for you to run ROS stuff, and orocos_kdl should be removed as it has been replaced by a newer catkin version of the package. I just now removed it from the list of dry (rosbuild) packages to be downloaded as part of the source installation, so in the future this version of orocos_kdl will not even be downloaded.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-03-12**:
Thanks for this, William. I appreciate your filing those bug reports too! As to the orocos_kdl issue, indeed I have cppunit installed, and running that command individually doesn't help unfortunately. It sounds either like an issue with the code, or one with the CLang compiler on OS X...

**Comment by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) on 2013-03-13**:
I believe I fixed the bug in "visualization_tutorials" (by adding the word "const").  If that doesn't make it work, please re-open the bug on github.  Thanks!

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-03-13**:
Thanks @hersh. That's great. Perhaps some instructions should be put on the OS X installation wiki page now, so people can patch it appropiately. :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure rospkg and rosdep are up-to-date, and that no old versions of them remain.

You can find out the version used by caling rospkg--version, and if there are old files, this call should tell you where they lie:

```
python -c 'import rospkg; print(rospkg.__file__)'
```

UPDATE: version 0.10.4 is okay.

Can you also try:
python -c 'import rosdep2; print(rosdep2.**file**)'

This is the folder where a rospack.py or rospack.pyc is searched for, but apparently not found. I don't have MacOS, so I cannot tell whether the location is right.

Maybe also look at this answer:
http://answers.ros.org/question/53110/rviz-runtime-error-in-groovy-at-mac-os-xhomebrew/

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-28**:
That python command prints a single line; `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rospkg/__init__.pyc`. As for `rosdep --version`, it returns 0.10.14. That is all okay, surely? What could it be?

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-28**:
Googling the Python error relating to importing *urandom* reveals it seems to be something to do with virtualenv (or virtual environments in general). I'm not aware Catkin/CMake uses anything like this, however?

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-28**:
Okay, the *urandom* errors are sorted now. I'm just left with a bunch of errors concerning CMake/OSX: http://pastie.org/pastes/6357394/text.

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-03-01**:
@KruseT: For `python -c 'import rosdep2; print(rosdep2.__file__)'`, I get `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosdep2/__init__.pyc`... which also seems okay. no? I will have a look at that answer, thanks.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-01**:
@Noldorin That location is correct, there is only one way to install rosdep/rospkg on OS X, via pip. So the ubuntu pip/debian conflict is not an issue on OS X.

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-03-01**:
Ah right, fair enough. By the way, temporarily unlinking brew does at least eliminate the `urandom` errors.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-03-02**:
Can you maybe change your question and post an updated log, ideally just the relevant part? It seems to me that the rospack error only occurs after different errors, maybe in a context with a flawed env (which should also be fixed, but does not cuase your breakage).

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-03-02**:
@KruseT: The errors are exactly the same, I checked. Just with the python ones gone now...

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-03-02**:
Anyway here is the log from my latest run: http://pastie.org/6368348. Any thoughts? :)

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-03-03**:
I think you should create one new question for each package that fails, as those errors seem to be unrelated. Just run make inside the respective package folder, and paste the log from there, the whole rosmake log is a bit lengthy.

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-03-03**:
@KruseT: Fair enough, will try later. Does that also mean you have no ideas about any of the remaining errors?

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-03-03**:
Yes, I would say else.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to fix the first missing symbols problem with `nodelet_tutorial_math` by adding a dependency to `class_loader` in **common_tutorials/nodelet_tutorial_math/manifest.xml** with the line

```
<depend package="class_loader"/>
```

I am sure if the correct thing to do, but at least the package now links successfully for me under 10.8.3.

---

Originally posted by [jensenb](https://answers.ros.org/users/4449/jensenb/) with karma: 316 on 2013-03-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1